# BLTouch fix for heated enclosure

Tags: marlin, bltouch

I print using a heated chamber but need to use a BLTouch to level my print bed.
I followed the pictures in the Reddit post ["Bltouch working temperature and fail"](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/jj0s9r/comment/hpp845a/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and moved the brains of my BLTouch outside the enclosure.

The BLTouch now does not have any failures in the 60 °C chamber, however, it now probes the bed distance in a range of about .075 mm, all the time, not affected by temperature. I found that by running `M48`, the max and min of the sample of probes are still extremely consistent.

I would like to be able to run `M48` and take a sample of probes, then average the max and min of that output and use that for my homing location in replace of `G28`.

This would let me get precise homing in my heated chamber using the BLTouch. Here is the output from running `M48` with 14 probes each time:

```
>>> M48 P14
SENDING:M48 P14
M48Z-Probe Repeatability Test
Finished!
Mean: -0.040536 Min: -0.069 Max: 0.006 Range: 0.075
Standard Deviation: 0.030517
>>> M48 P14
SENDING:M48 P14
M48Z-Probe Repeatability Test
Finished!
Mean: -0.025357 Min: -0.068 Max: 0.007 Range: 0.076
Standard Deviation: 0.030524
>>> M48 P14
SENDING:M48 P14
M48Z-Probe Repeatability Test
Finished!
Mean: -0.026027 Min: -0.069 Max: 0.012 Range: 0.081
Standard Deviation: 0.034820
»>› M48 P14
SENDING:M48 P14
M48Z-Probe Repeatability Test
Finished!
Mean: -0.015313 Min: -0.065 Max: 0.009 Range: 0.074
Standard Deviation: 0.028993
>>› M48 P14
SENDING:M48 P14
M48Z-Probe Repeatability Test
Finished!
Mean: -0.026429 Min: -0.066 Max: 0.012 Range: 0.078
Standard Deviation: 0.032845
»›› M48 P14
SENDING:M48 P14
M48Z-Probe Repeatability Test
Finished!
Mean: -0.019286 Min: -0.059 Max: 0.009 Range: 0.069
Standard Deviation: 0.028283
33› M48 P14
I SENDING:M48 P14
M48Z-Probe Repeatability Test
Finished!
Mean: -0.006696 Min: -0.062 Max: 0.011 Range: 0.072
Standard Deviation: 0.022003
»>› M48 P14
SENDING:M48 P14
M48Z-Probe Repeatability Test
Finished!
Mean: -0.022500 Min: -0.061 Max: 0.011 Range: 0.072
Standard Deviation: 0.031366
ass M19 D1A
SENDING:M48 P14
M48Z-Probe Repeatability Test
Finished!
Mean: -0.026339 Min: -0.063 Max: 0.012 Range: 0.076
Standard Deviation: 0.032574
»>› M48 P14
SENDING:M48 P14
M48Z-Probe Repeatability Test
Finished!
Mean: -0.025089 Min: -0.064 Max: 0.014 Range: 0.078
Standard Deviation: 0.032170
```

Min and max data typed out:

-.076       .001
-.069       .006
-.068        .007
-.069        .012
-.065        .009
-.066        .012
-.059        .009
-.062        .011
-.061        .011
-.063        .012
-.064        .014

I am relatively experienced in post-processing G-code and have done some editing of firmware for my printer (Ender 3 v2), however, I am not close to being an expert in either.